# ASP.NET onBlur method generating error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, onblur

I have an **aspx.page** in which this TextBox lives.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicyNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="90px" OnTextChanged="txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur"></asp:TextBox>
```

Every time I click into this TextBox, type something and click away (lose focus) I wish for this method to execute.

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPolicyNumber.TextChanged
    txtPlanCode.Text = Company.Applications.ProductionEngine.BusinessAccess.ManualAdjustmentsBusinessAccess.GetPlanCode(txtPolicyNumber.Text)
End Sub
```

This method basically calls an ExecuteScalar and returns a value from the database.

**SQL**

```
SELECT PolicyPlanCode
FROM bo.PolicyTransactions
WHERE PolicyNumber = @policyNumber
AND PolicyTransactionRowNumberAsc = 1
```

txtPolicyNumber holds the value which is passed in as parameter @policyNumber.

As soon as I load the page this error occurs.

**Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur' is not a member of 'ASP.reporting_manualadjustments_aspx'**

What I need to do is when txtPolicyNumber loses focus, txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur should be called and the result from the Sub txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur() should appear in the txtPlanCode.Text textbox.

Any ideas as to why this error comes up? Happy to make any further clarifications.

Comment: All the browser is saying is that it can't find the txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur javascript function. Is this function located on the page and in a script block? Take a look at the F12 tools to view the DOM that's being returned to verify the function exists on the client.

Comment: If you expect a VB method to be executed then you have to post back to the server. The ASP.NET code you have is specifying a JavaScript function to execute client-side, not a VB function to execute server-side.

Comment: I would prefer to execute a VB method but I tried creating an event for the textbox when it loses focus but that didn't work either. I've updated the code with that portion of code.

Comment: You're using the browser's javascript onblur event to invoke the server's vb.net function. One language is not compatible with another language.

Comment: Updated post with with my current code.

Comment: What happens if you manually build the site and try that page again?

Comment: You mean when I go the build menu up top and click build without running the page then running the page seperately after it builds?

Comment: If that’s what you mean it does the same thing. From what I saw it also describes a compiler error which I’ll be able to upload tomorrow when I get back into work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Fix**

Your page can't see the method because it's private, set it to protected.

```
Protected Sub txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur(...
```

**Need to decide**

You handle the even in two places. One in the tab and the other at the end of the method with the keyword Handle. Chose one, both do the same thing in the end.

If you decided to just use Handles and not do it in the tag, then you can set your method back to Private.

**Note**

I'm not sure if you are aware, but the browser need to refresh the page to go back to the server. Doing a TextChanged might not do what you expect. Also, rename your method from OnBlur to TextChanged.

Comment: I’ll check it out tomorrow and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @NikosV "Handles" is there to hook up the event to your method. When the text will change, the event will fire and your method will be called.

Comment: I realised and removed the comment. Thanks. I’ll post back tomorrow when I try the solution. However I am wondering why “TextChanged” if the text never changes? All I’m doing is going off focus. Does TextChanged also cover that?

Comment: @NikosV only when the text is changed after a postback. The AutoPostBack make the post back after a blur. The ideal way would be to do it in jQuery with a callback (ajax).

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t quite understand. MSDN says that TextChanged occurs when the value of a TextBox changes. Since my value isn’t changing and all we’re doing is navigating away from the Textbox why is TextChanged what we need? I’m just a bit confused. I just want an event to fire when the textbox goes off focus. How is that changing the value of the textbox? Thanks.

Comment: @NikosV then you'll need to do this with JavaScript. This is a bit out of scope of this question.

Comment: So in addition to your answer, I’ll also need JavaScript. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear why 90% of all examples on the Internet mention using JavaScript, this works perfectly fine having done just the changes suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hi onblur is not a server side event it's a client side event meaning you have to write javascript method and provide it in that event and your local browser will call it.
If you want to do any postback in it you have to do so using ajax.

however OnTextChanged is a similar sever side event if you want to fire it on text change automatically just name your sever side vb.net method in it and set AutoPostBack property to true. AutoPostBack="True"

eg(also remove parenthesis in method when you are specifying sever side event.)

```
<asp:TextBox AutoPostBack="True"
 ID="txtPolicyNumber" runat="server" Width="80px" OnTextChanged="txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Getting this message 'txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur' is not a member of 'ASP.reporting_manualadjustments_aspx'

Comment: try this method signature in your vb code                                                                txtPolicyNumber_OnBlur(sender As Object, _ 
  e As EventArgs) Handles currencyTextBox.TextChanged

Comment: Ok. I'l get back to you in a moment.

Comment: Same thing happening. I'm not sure if this plays a role I'm running Visual Studio 2010...

Comment: I don't thing that's a problem. Check if your page directive is <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB.net"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="" Inherits="" %> code behind and inherits are pointing to your class in which your code is(CodeBehind="your file name " Inherits=" your class name" )

Comment: eg <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB.net" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebTest._Default" %>

Comment: <%@ Page Language="vb" Title="" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ManualAdjustments.aspx.vb"
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" Inherits="Company.Applications.ProductionEngine.UI.ManualAdjustments" %> Does the same thing.

Comment: ashish updated the code to my current code if it helps.